# Need to return a differet value depending on what another ID equals

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a form, in the begining of that form there is a dropdown for years, currently having 3 options:

```
2021-2022
2022-2023
2023-2024
```

This element has the ID value of AidYear. And is created by using

```
data-bind="dynamicYear: { format: 'YYYY-YYYY[-2, 0]' } "
```

Later in the form, about 3/4 of the way down, we ask the question, "Were you born before January 1, YYYY?"

I need YYYY to populate with a different value depending on which option they chose from the original dropdown:

If 2021-2022 was selected, then YYYY should display a value of 1998.
If 2022-2023 was selected, then YYYY should display a value of 1999.
If 2023-2024 was selected, then YYYY should display a value of 2000.
So the final result is that the person using the form should see the question like:
"Were you born before January 1, 1999?"

Before selecting an option in the dropdown, it needs to default to 1998 like:
"Were you born before January 1, 1998?"

The new year should simply update once they select an option.

Due to the nature of the form, I need to do this all in a single line.

So far, I have not had any luck getting it to return anything. Below is one my many attempts.

Were you born before January 1,

```
<strong id="birthbefore1"></strong>  
<script> 
var birthdate2 = document.getElementById("AidYear");
if (birthdate2 = "") {"1998";}
if (birthdate2 = "2021-2022") {"1998";}
if (birthdate2 = "2022-2023") {"1999";}
if (birthdate2 = "2023-2024") {"2000";}
var p = document.getElementById("birthbefore1");
p.innerHTML = birthdate2;
</script>
```

I get zero results or when playing with some differences it sometimes results in
`[object HTMLSelectElement]` or even just errors out the form builder.

Comment: JavaScript uses `=` for assignment; your `if` statements should probably be using `==` or `===` to test equivalency between two objects instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright after trying everyones suggestions and nothing working correctly I have finally solved my own problem. First I needed to add the following to my viewmodel.js file:

```
vm.AidYear = ko.observable(""); // Starts with no selection
vm.BirthYear = ko.observable("1998"); // Starts with no birthYear
```

And then in the afterload I needed to place:

```
   vm.afterLoad = function afterLoad(){
    
      vm.AidYear.subscribe(function (selectedYear) {
            if (selectedYear === "2021-2022") {
                vm.BirthYear("1998");
            } else if (selectedYear === "2022-2023") {
                vm.BirthYear("1999");
            } else if (selectedYear === "2023-2024") {
                vm.BirthYear("2000");
            } else{
                vm.BirthYear('1998');
            }
         });

  
    };
```

And then on my element in the text field where the date is going to be placed I needed to have:

```
Were you born before January 1, <span data-bind="text: BirthYear"> </span> ?
```

All in all a fairly simply fix. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. You just need to add onchange event to AidYear, to trigger the updateBirthYear.

```html
<label for="AidYear">Select Aid Year:</label>
<select id="AidYear" onchange="updateBirthYear(this.value)">
  <option value="2021-2022">2021-2022</option>
  <option value="2022-2023">2022-2023</option>
  <option value="2023-2024">2023-2024</option>
</select>

<p>Were you born before January 1, <strong id="birthbefore1">1998</strong>?</p>

<script>
function updateBirthYear(birthdate2) {
  var birthYear;

  switch (birthdate2) {
    case "2021-2022":
      birthYear = "1998";
      break;
    case "2022-2023":
      birthYear = "1999";
      break;
    case "2023-2024":
      birthYear = "2000";
      break;
    default:
      birthYear = "1998";
  }

  document.getElementById("birthbefore1").innerHTML = birthYear;
}
</script>
```

Comment: The AidYear dropdown is at the beginning of the form, the "were you born before January 1, YYYY" statement is about 3/4 of the way down the form. Currently the AidYear dropdown use's this to get the resutls I need: data-bind="dynamicYear: { format: 'YYYY-YYYY[-2, 0]' } " So what do I need to add to the AidYear element and what needs to be put in the Were you born before.... area? If I simply add what you have above then it will create a new drop down next to that sentence, but it needs to be calling on the drop down from previous not making a new one.

Comment: You can just add an onchange event to the existing AidYear dropdown and update the "Were you born before January 1, YYYY" statement accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the strings using the asigning operator `=` instead of the using comparison operator `==` or `===`, also I included an `onchange` event listener that calls updateYear(this.value), which passes the currently selected value to the function

```
<p>Were you born before January 1, <strong id="birthbefore1">1998</strong></p>
    
    <select id="AidYear" onchange="updateYear(this.value)">
      <option value="2021-2022">2021-2022</option>
      <option value="2022-2023">2022-2023</option>
      <option value="2023-2024">2023-2024</option>
    </select>
    
    <script>
    function updateYear(birthdate2) {
      var year;
    
      if (birthdate2 == "2021-2022") {
        year = "1998";
      } else if (birthdate2 == "2022-2023") {
        year = "1999";
      } else if (birthdate2 == "2023-2024") {
        year = "2000";
      }
    
      document.getElementById("birthbefore1").innerHTML = year;
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: The AidYear dropdown is at the beginning of the form, the "were you born before January 1, YYYY" statement is about 3/4 of the way down the form. 

Currently the AidYear dropdown use's this to get the resutls I need:

`data-bind="dynamicYear: { format: 'YYYY-YYYY[-2, 0]' } "`

So what do I need to add to the AidYear element and what needs to be put in the Were you born before.... area? If I simply add what you have above then it will create a new drop down next to that sentence, but it needs to be calling on the drop down from previous not making a new one.,

Answer (score 0):

The value assigned to `birthbefore1` can be determined using subtraction. This can be used to generalise the solution and prevent the need to make additional updates to the code in future.

```
"2021-2022" : 2021 - 23 = 1998
"2022-2023" : 2022 - 23 = 1999
"2023-2024" : 2023 - 23 = 2000
```

The following function can be used as an `onchange` event handler for the `AidYear` form element to perform the update.

```
function changeAidYear() {
  const aidYearValue = document.getElementById("AidYear").value;
  let birthYearValue = "1998";
  if (aidYearValue.length == 9) {
    birthYearValue = `${(aidYearValue.split('-')[0] - 0) - 23}`;
  }
  document.getElementById("birthbefore1").innerHTML = birthYearValue;
}
```

Comment: The AidYear dropdown is at the beginning of the form, the "were you born before January 1, YYYY" statement is about 3/4 of the way down the form. Currently the AidYear dropdown use's this to get the resutls I need: data-bind="dynamicYear: { format: 'YYYY-YYYY[-2, 0]' } " So what do I need to add to the AidYear element and what needs to be put in the Were you born before.... area? If I simply add what you have above then it will create a new drop down next to that sentence, but it needs to be calling on the drop down from previous not making a new one.

Comment: You edited your question and changed your requirements a day after you had received two answers. It's a bit silly to comment that the answers provided don't meet your new requirements.